# Review audit on a question with a downvote?

Tags: support, review, review-audits

I just had an audit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4011925). Yes, I passed it, but why was there still an audit if there was already a downvote on the question (not from me)? At the time of review, the score was +14/-1. I thought that downvoting or voting to close a question rendered it ineligible for audits, so could someone clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criteria for audits are different in different queues, reflecting the goals of those queues. For the close and reopen queues, the criteria are extremely strict due to the seriousness of the actions being considered - you're probably thinking of those criteria when you mention downvotes making a question ineligible.

For the First Posts / Late Answers queues, we just look for a recent post scoring more than 10 that isn't closed/locked/deleted/community-wiki. The theory is, most posts able to garner that should be a fair bit above par for new user posts.